# Forum as an C# WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, forum, webrequest

sry for my bad english 
heres my problem,
i'm programming the first time with c# and i'm on to write a Forum as an app so you can see the threads and you can post. So from the admin I know that i have to make a Http-Request to an specific URL. with the parameters: login and password. and the action is Login. Also I have to save the hash and use him for the next requests. Can anybody help me wth this problem?

```
namespace PhoneApp8
{
    public partial class Login{
    public async Task<string> SendJSONData(string  https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx, string JSONData)
        {
        // server to POST to
        string url =  https://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx;

        // HTTP web request
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "action";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Write the request Asynchronously 
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            //create some json string
            string json = JSONData;

            // convert json to byte array
            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Write the bytes to the stream
            await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
        return webResponse;
    }
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Konstruktor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Beispielcode zur Lokalisierung der ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted so far?  What is the specific problem you're having with your code?

Comment: @KevinJ i added it to my post, but it was all trash

Comment: You might be intersted in `OAuth`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: What specific problem are you having with this code?  Also, you can look here for an example of logging into a forum with C#: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/221349/trying-to-login-to-a-forum-via-c-winforms-application-using-httpwebrequest#